# Suppressing print dialog during Internet Explorer automation

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am in the middle of a huge project which requires me to link up many outdated, but still useful intranet based data systems via a spreadsheet which analyses the data accordingly. I am nearing the end of the project and have begun to link up the last of these systems. However the issue I am having is that the main webpage that data is loaded from has an onLoad event which effectively opens up the print dialog. As this system is loading the data in the background this is unwanted behaviour.

Unfortunately our data management team still require this system in it's current form and so changing the webpage itself is not possible.

The webpage has the following code which is causing the issues:

```
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" background bgProperties="fixed" onload="javascript:printform();" >
```

As well as the script that fires the command to open the print dialog screen:

```
<Script Language='JavaScript'>
function printform()
{
    print();
}
</script>
```

When I have googled a solution I have struggled to find many resources on this topic, but the most promising one was using the line `ie.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER`. Where ie is an internetexplorer object. However in my testing this did not prevent the dialog from appearing. Any help or pointers you can give would be greatly appreciated. For completeness, the following is the  calling code as it currently stands:

```
Private ie As InternetExplorer
Private doc As HTMLDocument
Private pBarcodeStandard As String

Private Sub IE_Wait()

Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState = READYSTATE_LOADING: DoEvents: Loop

End Sub
Public Sub Import_TES_Data()

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate "https://company.intranet.page.here/"
IE_Wait
Set doc = ie.document
doc.getElementsByName("itemNum")(0).value = pBarcodeStandard
doc.forms(0).submit

'After submitting the form (at this point) the webpage loads with the onLoad command

End Sub
```

Comment: 1) Not efficient but can you code to click and close the object? Can you inspect it and use its HTML content to target a click and close? 2) More efficient: Can you find a way to intercept this event and do a replace on the response HTML  to swop out  onload="javascript:printform();  with vbnullString before loading into htmldocument.innerHTML? If possible, perhaps this can be done on the actual returned .document as opposed to creating a separate HTMLDocument and loading the altered HTML.

Comment: Did you give this a try?